# C# Recursive function return index of string in array (without IndexOf function)

Tags: c#, recursion

for example

```
find( new string[] { "Hello", "How are you", "Good Bye" }, "How are you" )
```

if I run this method I will output 1.

Requested to help me.Thanks.

Comment: please reformulate you question, it is not clear what is the question.

Comment: i can't create this function

Comment: i can with IndexOf, but it's need me without IndexOf

Comment: Why does this need to be recursive? That's not how you'd write such a method. Is it homework?

Comment: yes,it's homework

Comment: It's a terrible way to learn about recursion - shame on your teachers. Using recursion for something which should be done via iteration is just bad. They should be teaching you recursion with something that actually benefits from it!

Answer (score 2):

If you inisit on *recursion* and want to return index as a result (`-1` if no such `toFind` string has been found) you can try something like this:

```
 private static int find(string[] array, string toFind, int startFrom = 0) {
   if (startFrom >= array.Length)        // The array has been scanned up, no match found
     return -1;
   else if (array[startFrom] == toFind)  // match 
     return startFrom;
   else                                  // recursion check of the next item
     return find(array, toFind, startFrom + 1); 
 }
```

...

```
 int test = find( new string[] { "Hello", "How are you", "Good Bye" }, 
                 "How are you" );
```

Comment: Hmm I bet this code looks quite unclear for a newbie doing some homework. Some brackets would give it some structure.